# How to check the date of the current day is equal to date that store in database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to find how many new daily subscriptions are in my application, but when use `equal`and `compareTo` method the counter will be zero, but in my data, there is three new daily subscriptions.

```
String sql = "select paidDate from traineeJoinPayment; ";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
Date date1 = new Date();
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
int dayCount = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(rs.getString(1));
    if ((date2.equals(date)))
        dayCount++;
}
```

Also, I'm trying to make another separate example was made, but the result was the same.

```
String rs = "2022-01-21";
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(rs);
Date date1 = new Date();
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
System.out.println(date.equals(date2));
```

Also here is the output `false`

Note: The below date when execute the above query in MySQL

```
2022-01-05
2022-01-02
2022-01-06
2022-01-08
2021-12-30
2022-01-01
2022-01-21
```

Comment: Side note: Hmm, I'm not that much of a Java guy, so I might miss something, but it looks like you fetch the column for the whole table to then apply a filter and count the matching rows in `Java`. Do you realize, you could do that directly in a query to the DB, which is very likely a whole lot cheaper?

Comment: Try with something like `select count(*) from traineeJoinPayment where paidDate >= ? and paidDate < ?`

Comment: That's a plain sql-thing: `select count(*) from traineeJoinPayment where paidDate = CURDATE()`

Comment: I suspect the time portion of `java.util.Date`, which is a superclass of `java.sql.Date`, is interfering with `equals`...

Comment: Tanks a lot all, i solve it this issue using `Turo` query ,
`

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use either `Date` class. Both of these terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and supported in JDBC 4.2 and later. Specifically, `java.sql.Date` is replaced by `LocalDate`.

## Use the database, Luke

Generally best to leverage the database for as much work as is feasible. Database engines are usually highly optimized and best suited for tasks such as searching and comparing.

So rather than bring a bunch of rows over to Java for filtering, ask the database to do the query.

Determining the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

## SQL

Your SQL query will look something like the following.

```sql
SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE date_ = ? ;
```

## Java

On the Java side, supply the date.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , today ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```